# Dependency check while installing a component

Tags: component, installation

Suppose, one component is dependant upon the presence of another component. I found a function that is activated before installation:

create a file "script.php":

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
import( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );

class com_helloWorldInstallerScript
{
    /**
     * Runs just before any installation action is preformed on the component.
     * Verifications and pre-requisites should run in this function.
     *
     * @param  string    $type   - Type of PreFlight action. Possible values are:
     *                           - * install
     *                           - * update
     *                           - * discover_install
     * @param  \stdClass $parent - Parent object calling object.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function preflight($type, $parent) 
    {
        if($type === 'install')
        {   
            // Check if component is installed
            if ( !JComponentHelper::isEnabled( 'com_clients', true) )
            {
                echo 'com_clients is either not enabled or not installed';
                //How to stop installation process and output an error here?
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'com_clients is installed and enabled';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Add reference to manifest XML file:

```
<!-- Runs on install/uninstall/update; New in 2.5 -->
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Questions:

1. How to check the version of installed component?
2. How to stop installation process and output an error if the required component is not installed?

Answer (score 2):

**1. question**

You can get the database version of a component by running this:

```
private function getDatabaseVersion() {
    // Get the extension ID
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();


    $eid = $this->getExtensionId();

    if ($eid != null) {
        // Get the schema version
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('version_id')
            ->from('#__schemas')
            ->where('extension_id = ' . $db->quote($eid));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $version = $db->loadResult();

        return $version;
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Loads the ID of the extension from the database
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
private function getExtensionId() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('extension_id')
        ->from('#__extensions')
        ->where($db->qn('element').' = '.$db->q('XXXXXXXXXX'). ' AND type='. $db->q('component'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $eid = $db->loadResult();

    return $eid;
}
```

I grabbed this from my code. Feel free to customize it. Have a look at the XXXXX first. If you need the component version, you can check the manifest_cache column of the #__extensions table.

**2. question:**

you can do something like this in your preflight method:

```
if (version_compare($versionA, $versionB, 'gt')) {
    $msg = "Downgrades are not supported.";
    throw new Exception($msg, 100);
}
```

Comment: `throw new Exception($msg, 100);` - tried it, but for some reason it didn't work, the component was installed successfully. Maybe, I did something wrong. Will add a MWE tomorrow.

Comment: Is your preflight code executed at all?

Comment: No, it seems that it's not executed. Why can it be?

Comment: Got it the class name was com_HelloWorld, while I needed om_AuditingChecks.

Comment: One thing: my custom components don't have their version added to extensions table. What can be wrong?

Comment: #__extensions contains just the component manifest in the manifest column. If you add a version there, it'll end up in that table. The #__schemas table contains the database version of a component and is derived from the content of the SQL update folder.